# How do I secure the game's post to the online Highscore in WP7?

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-7

I've just started programming a online highscore for the first time, and it's for my WP7 game. I've seen some similar threads, but the lack of specific c# examples to the WP7 keeps me staggering :(

Right now I'm using get to my PHP/Mysql server, pretty straight forward:

```
http://host.com/highscore/add.php?username=foo&score=12345&gamegamefoo
```

But if any hackers got the hold of my url, and I think thats a fairly easy job, you could enter anything.

Realizing that I can't make a 100% secure highscorelist, I would like to do the 2nd or even 3rd best thing. I want to make it a bit more difficult then what I'm already doing.

Do anyone have anything specifics on what I could do?

Comment: Is SSLing a POST not an option?

Comment: no its not. my webserver subscription is very basic. if my game is a hit ill invest the time and money to up the security

Comment: Too bad.  You really don't have much of an option other than security by obscurity.  Even if you encode your GET values, the method of encoding will be relatively easy to locate in your xbap.

Comment: There are free hosting services that allow the use of HTTPS, including Google's App Engine (for Python/Java/Go). I'd imagine for something as simple as a high score board, that an App Engine app would be a fairly reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into `basic authentication`.  In it's simplest form, you just need to create a user on your server with a password which your client will use to authenticate with. The server will check to make sure that that the credentials sent by the client match before doing anything else.

Preferably your server would be using `https` so that the username and password sent by your client isn't sent in clear text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no security expert but one thing you could do is put the username/highscore combo through some kind of one way hash, like md5 or SHA-1 and supply the hash as another parameter. Then on your server you do the same again and make sure they match.

Obviously your hash key is hackable from your game code, but a lot safer than a public url.